# How to go to next/previous symbol occurrence in semantic-mode of emacs?

Tags: emacs

With my cursor on a symbol (a variable name or a function call) I am able to jump to its definition using **semantic-ia-fast-jump**. I am also able to highlight the symbols occurrence using **global-semantic-idle-local-symbol-highlight-mode**. But how do I navigate to the next or previous occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any semantic-mode commands that do exactly what you want.
That being said, why don't you just use emacs search commands that do the same thing?    C-s to search forward and    C-r to search backwards.
See [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Incremental-Search.html#Incremental-Search)

Comment: I don't use C-s and C-r because they require you to yank the search string to mini-buffer. Anyway, I found the solution at [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SearchAtPoint), using highlight-symbol-mode it can be done in one key stroke with cursor placed on the tag you want to search.